# Why my head pointer is changing in linked list,even not passing it by reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, linked-list, null-pointer

I created a linked list, and made a function `reverseList` which takes a pointer to head and return pointer to last node.

```
Node* reverseList(Node *head)
{
  Node* curr=head;
  Node* prev=NULL;
  Node* ahead;
  while(curr!=NULL)
  {
    ahead=curr->next;
    curr->next=prev;
    prev=curr;
    curr=ahead;
  }
return prev;
}
```

But in main when I am doing this

```
int main()
{
  int n;///no of elements in list
  cin>>n;

  Node* head=NULL;
  head=createList(head,n);///creating list(it is working properly)
  printList(head);

  cout<<endl;
  Node* temp=reverseList(head);///reversing list and storing address of list in 
  //new node
  printList(temp);///printing reversed list properly

  cout<<endl;

  printList(head);///while printing this it is printing only one elements, 
  //which implies head pointer changes but I don't know
  ///how
}
```

My head pointer changes, and it is printing only one value. I had pass my head pointer in `reverseList` by value. I am providing image of output.

[image: image of output]

Comment: Add the code for printList().

Comment: No, `head` pointer didn't change. It used to point to a node with the data of 1, and it points to that node now. `head->next` did change.

Comment: Isn't `temp` your new list head after reversal?? You never changed `head`, so it's still pointing to what it was before: `1` (and since you reversed your list and that is now the last node, it's `next` points to NULL printing a list starting at `head` gives only that node).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: can you suggest me some edits to do this operation without changing `head->next`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @SuhailAkhtar *"without changing head->next"* - well, then you simply cannot reverse... When reversing the a linked list, the previous head element needs to get the last element and *must* have a null pointer as next (unless you want to implement a circular list). So you need to change the head pointer *itself* -- you could pass it as *reference* to the function and then reassign it inside (return value then would not be needed any more...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comments explain fine already, trying to illustrate to make it a little clearer:

```
  1 > 2 > 3 > 4 > NULL
  ^
 head
```

Now you reverse the list, resulting in:

```
  4 > 3 > 2 > 1 > NULL 
  ^           ^
 temp        head
```

As you never changed `head`, it still points to the same node as it pointed to before the list reversal, but after reversing the list, this node is now the last one.

Side note: Forgetting to re-assign is quite a common error, so it is a good idea to encapsulate the linked list in a separate class:

```
class LinkedList
{
    Node* _head;
public:
    class Node; // just as you have already
    void reverse() // now a member function
    {
        //reverse as you did before

        // encapsulating the assignment: (!)
        _head = newHead;
    }

    Node* head() { return _head; }
};

LinkedList l;
// ...
Node* tmp = l.head();
l.reverse();
// tmp variable points to tail...
// expecting tmp pointing to head is still an error,
// and there is no way to prevent it
// BUT the correct head can always be re-acquired:
head = l.head();
```

**Edit** in response to comment:

If you want to create a *new* list, you will have to *copy* the nodes:

```
Node* createReversedList(Node* head)
{
    Node* cur = NULL;
    while(head)
    {
        Node* tmp = new Node(*head);
        // (provided you have an appropriate copy constructor)

        tmp->next = cur;
        cur = tmp;
        head = head->next;
    }
    return cur;
}
```

Note the new name, `reverse` rather implies modifying the original list as you did.

Comment: Sir, can you please suggest me some edits, to carry out this operation. I want to create a new reversed list, not reverse the existing list .Thanx

Answer (score 0):

To create a new Linked List, you need to create a new variable of `Node`, and perform operations on that variable.

So, the code would be something like:

```
Node* reverseList(Node *head)
{
    Node* newRootPtr = new Node(); //Pointer to the new root. This will be returned to the calling function.

    newRootPtr->next = NULL;        //In the reversed list, the original head will be the last node.

    Node* curr=head;                //For iterations

    while(curr->next!=NULL)         //For every node, until the last node. Note that here, we need to stop at the last node, which will become the first node of the new List.
    {
        Node ahead=*(curr->next);   //Create a new Node equal to the next node of the original list.
        Node* aheadPtr = &ahead;        //Pointer to the new node
        aheadPtr->next = newRootPtr;    //Point the new node to the previous node of the new list
        newRootPtr = aheadPtr;          //update root node
        curr=curr->next;
    }

    return newRootPtr;
}
```